# HTTP ERROR 500 after deploy on web service

Tags: .net, web-services, azure-web-app-service

I was deploy my app on Azure Web Service.
The app works locally but when I deploy to Azure I get internal server error (500).
I already clicked on "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" on Set Server Firewall.

```
Most likely causes:

IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.
```

And I go to KUDU Console at `https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net` . I found the web.config file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\CRM_BackEnd.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

So how can I resolve this?

My Program.cs is

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var defaultConnectionString = string.Empty;
    
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CRMDBContext>(option =>
{
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BE_CRM"));
});
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
builder.Services.Configure<PublitioApi>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("PublitioApi"));
builder.Services.Configure<SendGirdApi>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("SendGridApi"));
builder.Services.AddDependenceInjection();
builder.Services.AddSwagger();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    //app.UseSwagger();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();
        if(context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
        {
            context.Request.Path = "/swagger/index.html";
            await next(); 
        }
    });
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.RouteTemplate = "MyBackEnd/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/MyBackEnd/swagger/v1/swagger.json","CRM_BackEnd v1");
});
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader();
});
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseJwt();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And .csproj is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <UserSecretsId>1798ad59-2539-4d78-bdc2-fd2f9983b3e9</UserSecretsId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="BCrypt.Net-Next" Version="4.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Firebase.Auth" Version="1.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="FirebaseAdmin" Version="2.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="FirebaseAuthentication.net" Version="3.7.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="FirebaseStorage.net" Version="1.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.9" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.9" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.9">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Otp.NET" Version="1.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Publitio-NET" Version="1.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.28.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft" Version="6.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.25.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="firebasesdk.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ProjectExtensions><VisualStudio><UserProperties appsettings_1json__JsonSchema="" /></VisualStudio></ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

Comment: What is the framework you are using and how you have deployed the App to Azure ?

Comment: I'am using .NET 6.0 And I deploy by Github Actions

Comment: Could you please share your `.csproj` and `Program.cs` file.

Comment: Okey. wait a second

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it

Comment: Are you following any document ?

Comment: I dont know how but when I deploy again on Heroku. Log was display an error occurs. My error is couldn't load file .xml on bin folder (Azure not show me this error but Heroku did). And I already fixed. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, it can be useful for other community members.